# Does suspending an account allows access to CPanel?

Tags: cpanel

I have a CPanel reseller account, and I want to suspend a site because it was hacked, but I want to know if will be available to site owner to restore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When suspending a cPanel account, it will fully lock down the account... it prevents login into cPanel, SQL, Mail and all other services, crons and processes. The account can then only be restored via the Reseller administrator.

> [CKB What happens when you suspend an account?](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/What+Happens+When+You+Suspend+an+Account)
>
> The system uses the passwd -l command to lock the account's
>   /etc/shadow password file. This command prepends the account's
>   passwords with two exclamation marks (!!).    The following list includes
>   some of the effects that this action causes:
>
> ```
> - The user cannot log in to their cPanel account.
> - The account's database users cannot log in to their databases.
> - The suspended account's password cannot change.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Simon is right about what access they won't have.

I find the best way to handle a situation like this is to change the document root to something like `/public_html/temp` and then unsuspend the account for a negotiated length of time e.g. 48 hours

Comment: Thanks! Do you know where could I do this?

Comment: https://www.servint.net/university/article/the-tech-bench-changing-a-document-root-in-cpanel/